Fail to detect Aruco markers at the edges
I have this image where the marker with Id 67 is not properly detected (the corners are visibly underestimated). I can see there's room to find the corner but not sure why the Aruco detector does not like this marker. I tried to use polygonalApproxAccuracyRate and min/maxMarkerPerimeterRate but didn't have luck trying multiple combinations. If there's a missing knob I might not be considering I would appreciate any pointer. Also, not sure if there's a way to detect ocluded Arucos like the one under id=67.

int main() {
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("input.png", cv::IMREAD_UNCHAGED);
    std::vector<int> ids;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f> > corners;
    cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::Dictionary> dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_5X5_1000);
    cv::aruco::DetectorParameters detectorParams = cv::aruco::DetectorParameters();
    params.polygonalApproxAccuracyRate = 0.04 // I tried different values here
    params.maxMarkerPerimeterRate = 0.05      // here too
    params.minMarkerPerimeterRate = 0.06      // and here
    cv::aruco::ArucoDetector detector(dictionary, detectorParams);
    detector.detectMarkers(img, markerCorners, markerIds, rejectedCandidates);
    cv::aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(img, corners, ids);
    cv::write("output.png", img);
    return 0;
}


that's the issue with markers partially out of view. nobody really bothers to get that right. I mean the library implementations. that is also an issue with charuco calibration boards. -- best you can do is find markers with corners that are too close to the edge, and discard them. since the "quiet zone" around the marker is supposed to be visible anyway, I'd recommend something proportional to this, however big your markers can appear. you could also figure this as an absolute minimum border, or a larger distance if the marker appears really huge.

As a very temporary, low effort solution, try to pad your image with a few white pixels every side, creating an artificial quiet zone.
